# Как раскодировать код, который побывал в ioncube?

Tags: php

Есть ли какая-нибудь возможность раскодировать код, который побывал в `ioncube`?
Переискал уже в гугле, все делятся одними и теми же неработающими методами, программами и сайтами, которые уже давно умерли.

А проблема остается насущной:

```
<?if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted.\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);
?>
HR+cPur7Jbmr6xEJgOVRVoI2U4GQ9nPpK2QQNSnVamVAl07OIqSKBJgq4bCenqjEerI0oR3jcNB4
BuUHAbbvTPuuxHnSkEmAUq6UvhQxCrgVIKYlfZiPbYhcQQ+xqAIhFNVEmD6/2AQS1LPJ6b4+PweU
0s/R7WfYTJb4SBxsBFi+w+SbHiGQo627UMevcrhrZlIt0W3XmynOaplqFcKH4Rx0/qImrV/WtVtU
```

Comment: Судя по размеру - там кода кот наплакал, не проще свой написать?

Comment: Я не весь скопировал, и там не один класс.

Comment: я этой прогой ранее некоторые файлы декодировал, но возможно обновили алго шифрования:
http://files.planet-dl.org/Dezenders/DeZender.DeIoncuber.06.09.2011.7z

Comment: http://raz0r.name/articles/how-to-decrypt-php-script/